# Retornar vacio el valor de un text field clonado en Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, clone

Estoy utilizando VUEjs 2. Primeros pasos en la programacion. Cualquier otra forma mejor de lograr esto se les agradeceria. Estoy creando un creador de formularios aqui tengo el codigo en jsBin http://jsbin.com/vovevi/edit?html,css,output Necesito ayuda en la parte de crear los checkbox. Muchas gracias de antemano. *Primera vez que escribo en Stack *El problema es que al clonar el input ya sale con el texto que hayan escrito en el input clonado.

Div Clonado:

```
<div id="option" class="input-group form-group">
    <input id="" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Option" value=""> 
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn waves-effect btn-default btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger"></i></button>
</span> 
</div>
<div id="newOptions"> <!-- Div's clonados -->

</div>
<div class="pull-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn waves-effect btn-success btn-xs" @click="addOption"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i> Add option</button>
</div>
```

Este es mi JS

```
addOption: function(){
          var el = document.getElementById("option");
          var divClone = el.cloneNode(true),
              elChild = document.createElement("div"); 

          document.getElementById("newOptions").appendChild(divClone);
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

intenta utlizando esto justo despues de clonarlo, o como mejor practica deja un set de campos escondidos los cuales clonaras para usar, asi no tienes el problema de que vayan con texto que ingresa el usuario:

```
divClone.val('');
```